# What's the best, correct way way to optimize this code and find MIN and MAX value for each ROW/COLUMN

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make this code as efficient as possible, what is the best and most correct way to do this? Also, I need to find the MIN and MAX values for each column and row and display the values next to the specific row and column.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int ri, ki;
        int i, j;
        int max = 1;
        int min = 0;
        int rndnumber = rand.Next(64, 128);

        int[,] array = new int[9, 4]; // Izveido array 9x4 (rin x kol)

        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) //
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)

                array[i, j] = rand.Next(1, 100 + 1); 
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) //
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
            {
                Console.Write("|\t{0}\t ", array[i, j]); // /t - tab
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n"); // new line
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) // 
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)

            if (max < array[i, j]) // Aprekina max
            {
                    max = array[i, j];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Maksimalais sk tabula: {0}", max);
        Console.WriteLine("Min sk tabula: {0}", min);
        //rndnumber = rand.Next();
        //Console.WriteLine("Hello World {0}", rndnumber);
        Console.ReadKey();

        /* 
            Izveidot ka zem katras rindas un kol ir  min un max skaitlis    
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: You can fill/print/calc min max in the same loop. No need for multiple.

Answer (score 2):

If you make the multidimensional array into an `IEnumerable`, you can use Linq on it:

```
// Order and use Cast<int>() to get an ordered IEnumerable<int>,
var orderedAscending = from x in array.Cast<int>()
                       orderby x
                       select x;
// Use linq First() & Last() to get min and max.
var min = orderedAscending.First();
var max = orderedAscending.Last();
```